# Calculate age in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to output the age of the person rather than the Date of birth in these arrays.

```
$players = array (
  array("Name 1","Nickname 1","07-15-1986"),
  array("Name 2","Nickname 2","07-27-1985")
);

$totalPlayers = array_sum(array_map("count", $players))/3;

for ($row = 0; $row < $totalPlayers; $row++) {
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
    echo "<li>".$players[$row][$col]."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Current output

- Name 1
- Nickname 1
- 07-15-1986
- Name 2
- Nickname 2
- 07-27-1985

Comment: What problem are you having? Use `strtodate()` to parse the date column. Subtract that from `time()`, and convert that difference in seconds to a difference in years.

Comment: @Barmar What a great idea. I did not see your comment until after I posted my answer.

Comment: Wouldn't a `foreach` work better?  `foreach($totalPlayers as $player){   list($name1,$name2,$dob) = $player`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tad simpler:

```
<?
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $players = array (
      array("Name 1","Nickname 1","07-15-1986"),
      array("Name 2","Nickname 2","07-27-1978")
    );

    // today's date
    $date1 = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
    foreach ($players as $obj)
    {
        // must replace "-" by "/" otherwise strtotime will assume european format dd-mm-yy
        $date2 = date_create(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("-", "/", $obj[2]))));
        $interval = date_diff($date2, $date1);
        echo $obj[0]." (".$obj[1].") :".$interval->format('%R%y years %m months')."\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You do not need the str_replace() when the year is four digits

Answer (score 2):

This works +- a few days.

```
$age = floor((time() - strtotime(.$players[$row][2])) / 31540000);
```

Comment: There is no index 3.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$players = array (
    array("Name 1","Nickname 1","07-15-1986"),
    array("Name 2","Nickname 2","07-27-1985")
);

// Not sure why you didn't just use count...
$totalPlayers = count($players);

$now = new DateTime();

// Replace the date field in the array with the age of each player.
// Use the difference, in years, between today's date
//     and the player's birthday.
$players = array_map(
    function($item) use ($now) {
        $item[2] =
            $now->diff(
                DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $item[2])
            )->y . ' years old';
        return $item;
    },
    $players
);

for ($row = 0; $row < $totalPlayers; $row++) {
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        echo "<li>".$players[$row][$col]."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

// • Name 1
// • Nickname 1
// • 36 years old

// ...
```